Can I use `reactable` with groupBy and span several columns?
My data set has only two columns, but with rather some rather long strings. For example,
library(lorem) # for test data

dat <- data.frame(
    group=c( # 2 groups
        rep(as.character(lorem::ipsum(1)), 3), 
        rep(as.character(lorem::ipsum(1)), 3)
    ), 
    item=as.character(lorem::ipsum(6))
)

I want to display the data using reactable. I want to use groupBy to group the data. However, there is quite a lot of whitespace since the columns are shown side by side.
library(reactable)
reactable::reactable(
    dat,
    groupBy="group",
    compact=TRUE # no visible change IMO
)


Is there a way to make both the group column and the item column span both columns, maybe using custom rendering?
I tried wrap=TRUE but then information is lost. I also tried to provide a details function which displays the items as separate reactable, but then the search functionality is lost.
What I would like to achieve is something like this:


Not including the groupBy argument results in a well arranged table.

Just for reference, this is the solution I worked out, with the help of this answer and the docs
reactable::reactable(
    dat,
    groupBy="group",
    columns = list(
        group=reactable::colDef(
            name= " ",
            width=25, #px
            grouped = htmlwidgets::JS("function(cellInfo) {
                return ' '
            }")
        ),
        item=reactable::colDef(
            name = "Group / Item",
            aggregate = htmlwidgets::JS("function(values, rows) {
                return rows[0]['group'] + ' (' + rows.length + ')'
            }")
        )
    )
)



Perhaps this is the kind of output you are looking for:
library(lorem)
library(reactable)
library(reactablefmtr)

dat <- data.frame(
  group=c( # 2 groups
    rep(as.character(lorem::ipsum(1)), 3), 
    rep(as.character(lorem::ipsum(1)), 3)
  ), 
  item=as.character(lorem::ipsum(6))
)


reactable(dat,
          compact = F,
          searchable = T,
          striped = T,
          bordered = T,
          highlight = T,
          height = 620,
          theme = reactableTheme(
            stripedColor = "lightblue",
            borderColor = "lightblue",
            borderWidth = 3
          ))



Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, collapsible groups is a requirement.
